# How to refactor using the go_router package

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a flutter web project and when I finished most of the work I realized that there is a problem with the address bar in the browser, so I refactored the homepage using the go_router package, but I don't know how to refactor it, I need some ideas or an example to learn.

## Here is my code:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List pages = [
    const Index(),
    const Room(),
    const Task(),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("XXX"),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(children: [
          const FlutterLogo(),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Button(
              title: "Index",
              func: () {
                setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = 0;
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
          Button(
              title: "room",
              func: () {
                setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = 1;
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
          Button(
              title: "task",
              func: () {
                setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = 2;
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ]),
      ),
      body: pages[_currentIndex]
    );
  }
}
```

flutter -v: stable 3.10.6

I asked chatgpt, but it's bullshitting. I looked it up in google but couldn't find a correspondence

Comment: What is the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask